# Java: Load data into variables from a .yaml file

Tags: java, yaml

I've a Java program that should connect to two other machines (IP addresses and ports are known) and do a data comparison task.

Instead of hardcoding the IP and port in the Java source file, I created a `config.yaml` file and stored these there as follows, let's say this is the context of that file:

**config.yaml:**

```
other machines:
  -"firstMachineAddress:162.242.195.82"
  -"secondMachineAddress:50.31.209.229"
  -"firstTargetPort:4041"
  -"secondTargetPort:4042"
```

Now I want to load these values in my Java source file and assign them to the variables I created already, such as:

**sampleClass.java:**

```
// addresses of the machines which we will connect
    public final InetAddress firstMachineAddress = "";
    public final InetAddress secondMachineAddress = "";
    private final int firstTargetPort = "";
    private final int secondTargetPort = "";
```

I was wondering if Java provides a convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: jackson can do this for you

Comment: can be done in spring boot also

Comment: http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html have you tried this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml

> Copy paste below

### Maven dependency

To use this extension on Maven-based projects, use the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

### Usage

Usage is as with basic `JsonFactory`; most commonly you will just construct a standard `ObjectMapper` with `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory`, like so:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
User user = mapper.readValue(yamlSource, User.class);
```

but you can also just use underlying `YAMLFactory` and parser it produces, for event-based processing:

```
YAMLFactory factory = new YAMLFactory();
JsonParser parser = factory.createJsonParser(yamlString); // don't be fooled by method name...
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
  // do something!
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. It seems like the solution I want, however one thing I don't get. I am expecting to read the values from the `.yaml` file and assign them to the java variables. Here in the usage section, I see a class called `user` and `readValues()` function returns its values to the `user` object. I presume all the variables are in this object and one can reach them, right?